# Sublime text - select word and copy to clipboard macro

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext2

In Netbeans its possible to create a macro for selecting a word and copying it to clipboard

I wonder if its possible with Sublime Text 2 ?

Thanks for any help.

Edit : I understand that this is possible with a plugin.   But I dont know Python, if any Python developers can create a plugin for this, it would be awesome! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some searching I managed to find its solution.

And the solution is a plugin.

In the menu, go to Tools -> New Plugin ->

For select the text and copy, this is the plugin content

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SelectAndCopyCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command("find_under_expand")
        self.window.run_command("markSelection")
        self.window.run_command("copy")
```

And I saved it as select_and_copy.py

For the select and paste, this is the plugin content

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SelectAndPasteCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command("find_under_expand")
        self.window.run_command("markSelection")
        self.window.run_command("paste")
```

And I saved it as select_and_paste.py

And the last thing you need to do is to bind this to a keyevent.

For this, in the menu, go to - Preferences -> Key Bindings - User

I have this content.

```
[
    { "keys": ["alt+`"], "command": "select_and_copy" },
    { "keys": ["alt+1"], "command": "select_and_paste" }
]
```

So, thats it, hope this helps for someone ! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this with two keystrokes - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks Matt, Now, now, thats very close. :)
But, I wonder if there is any method to do this in single click ?

Comment: @AjeeshJoshy sorry, I just saw your comment - I'm not sure that you can assign a macro to a mouse action. You could write a plugin to do it, but my skills at plugin writing are only minimal at the moment. If you know Python, check out the [plugin reference docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/plugins.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I actually meant to say a single keystroke, I tried to write a plugin for it, but failed :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using a sublime macro. Create a file named select-copy.sublime-macro in your Package folder:

```json
[
  { "command": "find_under_expand" },
  { "command": "copy" }
]
```

And add the following entry to your key bindings file:

```
{
  "keys": ["ctrl+up"],
  "command": "run_macro_file",
  "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/select-copy.sublime-macro" }
},
```

And that's it, no plugin needed !
You can also record the macro if you don't want to dive into the config files to find the commands that you need:

```
Tool > Record Macro
Do some magic here.
Tool > Stop Recording Macro
Tool > Save Macro...
```

Comment: Worked well, except that I found expand select as a better solution:
```[
  { "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "word"} },
  { "command": "copy" }
]
```